# Deserialize nested level XML

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am trying to retrieve data from Zoho API and then I want to Deserialize a returned data in an object.

The XML structure:

```
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Potentials/getSearchRecords">
    <result>
        <Potentials>
            <row no="1">
                <FL val="POTENTIALID">0000000000000</FL>
                <FL val="SMOWNERID">000000000000</FL>
                .......
            </row>
            <row no="2">
                .......
            </row>
        </Potentials>
    </result>
</response>
```

And here what I tried but didn't succeed.

```
[Serializable()]
public class ZohoXML
{
    public ZohoXML() { }

    [XmlElement("POTENTIALID")]
    public string POTENTIALID { get; set; }
    ........
}

[XmlRoot("response")]
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement("result")]
    public Result[] ResultList { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [XmlArray("Potentials"), XmlArrayItem("row")]
    public Row[] RowList { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("row")]
public class Row
{
    [XmlArray("Potentials")]
    [XmlArrayItem("row", typeof(ZohoXML))]
    public ZohoXML[] ZohoXML { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I deserialize:

```
Response ZohoXMLCollection = null;

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strFile);
ZohoXMLCollection = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Can anybody please help on identifying an issue in the code ?

Comment: any particular reason for not considering LINQ2Xml

Comment: I find the best way to see where deserialization is going wrong is to run it in reverse, so serialize some data, and see where your output doesn't match the output your trying to deserialize.

Comment: @Anirudh Because I have no idea regarding that and haven't ever used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of VS you can use `Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML as Classes` in the edit menu. Assuming your XML structure is correct this will give you:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class response
{

    private responseResult resultField;

    private string uriField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public responseResult result
    {
        get
        {
            return this.resultField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.resultField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string uri
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uriField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uriField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class responseResult
{

    private responseResultRow[] potentialsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("row", IsNullable = false)]
    public responseResultRow[] Potentials
    {
        get
        {
            return this.potentialsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.potentialsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class responseResultRow
{

    private responseResultRowFL[] flField;

    private byte noField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FL")]
    public responseResultRowFL[] FL
    {
        get
        {
            return this.flField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.flField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte no
    {
        get
        {
            return this.noField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.noField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class responseResultRowFL
{

    private string valField;

    private byte valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string val
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public byte Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You will want to clean up the names but for now this is fine.

Then your de-serialization will look like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(response));
response res = new response();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileLocation))
{
      res = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as response;
}
```

Note that `StreamReader` implements the `IDisposable` interface so should be used within a `using` block to ensure automatic disposable of resources.